# Sequelize - MS SQL - Multiple result sets of stored procedure getting merged into one array

Tags: sequelize.js

We are using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) with MS SQL to retrieve data by executing stored procedures. The stored procedure is executed as RAW query.

Example:

```
EXEC spGetSummaryData;
```

The problem occurs when the `spGetSummaryData` procedure returns 2 result sets as the result of execution, but the result sets are getting merged into a single array.

```
 sequelize.query("EXEC spGetSummaryData;", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW})
  .then(function(summary) {
   // Summary has both the result sets merged into a single array.
  })
```

How to get the result sets separated into two different arrays than a single one?

Comment: Using a raw query in sequelize should just give you the result directly from the connector - have you tried executing the query using tedious?

Answer (score 0):

This is from another post I did for same issue but for quick accessibility, I will paste my response here and will add the link to original post as well:

> Here is a bit different approach I tried since I am also not able to get the multiple result sets from MSSQL database (Got single array with combination of multiple result sets) with all trials I performed using sequelize.js-v6 :

> Get the code of the stored procedure
> Split it up according to the result set, as backend engineer, you can do trial and errors updated code to get relevant result set or can ask directly to sql developer to get correct query for each result set.
> Create multiple calls using those queries and handle the result in nodeJS in the correct format that you needed to consume - OR - create multiple api's for multiple result set and use them for the given requirements.
> I know this is a kind of different approach or say a workaround but this worked for me. Hope this helps for any new visitor stuck with similar issue.

Link to the original post: [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74886961/11723512)